# What does the red symbol mean here?

Tags: altium, symbol

I found this symbol on the schematics of an FPGA board. AIN stand for Analog input.

[image: switches?]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you didn't cut off the picture, you'd see the wires are labelled `AIN15_P`, `AIN15_N`, `AIN16_P`, `AIN16_N`. The red symbol tells Altium that these signals (each matching `P` and `N` pair) should be considered a differential pair.

This can allow the layout tool to invoke special design rules for these nets, and the autorouter or interactive router to treat them specially.

Comment: Thanks. I cut it to focus on the symbol. This is from the schematics for Digilent's Cmod A7 board.

Comment: One question though, is this Altium Specific or does KiCad also have these directives?

Comment: No, this is a specific "directive" of Altium. I'm not sure if Kicad has something like this. At least not with the same symbol